# "The file could not be accessed, try one of the following" when importing table in an Excel web query

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, import

https://www3.epa.gov/twebhelp/WebHelp/tri_forms__instructionstri_forms_and_instructions6_new_table_ii_b_individually_listed_toxic_chemicals_arranged_by_cas_registry_number.htm

Trying to pull the data from this table in Excel, but although it seems to detect the table fine, it fails when actually importing it.  None of the suggested reasons in the prompt apply.  Does anyone know what might be causing this error?

The prompts I get are:
[image]
and
[image]

Comment: Excel is usually pretty good at pulling out tables constructed from divs from web pages.  Atlohugh it isn't really relevant to the technical question relating to importing the table, for the record, it's a public document for industry reference.  I found a more modern version provided at https://www.epa.gov/toxics-release-inventory-tri-program/tri-listed-chemicals anyway, but I'm still curious as to the technical question of what causes excel to fail at that page.

Comment: I tested the link and it seems that my initial curiosities were correct. I made some adjustment and cam up with a workaround for this unique question from the unique website. An import is possible with this workaround. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Causes of errors investigation:**

I believe the problem lies in two areas. Access, credentials to the website which may be blocking some aspect of Excel's query algorithm, which is hidden in the confines of Excel's program which is proprietary, which means we can't look at it. I assumed this and attempted to use Excel's Web Query from Web program and credentials were required to the root site. Performing a Query on the page, resulted in a null query. This satisfied my curiosities of why it's failing.

So I came up with a workaround. Also, manipulating a couple settings in the Option menu makes it possible to import this table.

**How to overcome these errors, via workaround:**

**Step 1)** Save the webpage document to your Desktop. While on the webpage perform: CTRL+S, Save-As, Webpage complete.

[image]

**Step 2)** Open your html file that you saved in Step-1. Use this local url as your query link.

[image]

**Step 3)** Perform the query in Excel as you did initially, using the url in Step-2: Data Tab → From Web → Address (step1) → Select by clicking the Option button before import process. In Options menu, make adjustment as to how you import. Use Full HTML Formatting by selecting the radio setting in the Options menu. Also uncheck the box labeled "Treat consecutive delimiters as one".  Click Okay.

[image]

**Step 4)** Click import without selecting anything on the import page.Do not select the table before clicking import. In this particular situation only an entire import will execute successfully.

[image]

**Finally the table imported.**

[image]